# How to download the latest `com.google.android.gms` using `sdkmanager`?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, android-sdk-manager

I tried `sdkmanager 'extras;google;m2repository'`, but the newest version installed , for example, in my `android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-auth` folder is `11.0.4`. And I want `15.0.1`. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason sometimes the dependencies don't update, to fix this click the terminal button at the bottom of Android Studio and enter the following command:

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

This will force the dependencies to reload and update.